# using list types with Haskell's -XDataKinds

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

I was using a return type in a function (using package [`haskell-src-exts`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts)):

```hs
import Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax (Exp(..))
import Language.Haskell.Exts.SrcLoc (SrcSpanInfo(..))
:k Exp SrcSpanInfo
Exp SrcSpanInfo :: *
```

That's a type. So far so good.

But now I wanted to type it better:

```hs
:set -XDataKinds
> :k 'List
'List :: l -> [Exp l] -> Exp l
```

So, this thing wants some more stuff. Fine, I can do that.

```
> :k 'List SrcSpanInfo 
'List SrcSpanInfo :: [Exp *] -> Exp *
```

One step off. Okay.

```
> :k 'List SrcSpanInfo [Exp SrcSpanInfo]

<interactive>:1:19: error:
    • Expected kind ‘[Exp *]’, but ‘[Exp SrcSpanInfo]’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the second argument of ‘ 'List’, namely ‘[Exp SrcSpanInfo]’
      In the type ‘ 'List SrcSpanInfo [Exp SrcSpanInfo]’
```

At this point, I'm feeling quite confused.
To me it feels like what I gave it was definitely pretty much what it asked for.
What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, it suddenly occurred to me that you're probably not actually looking for the lifted types (i.e. kinds), but rather for regular types.

From the comments (specifically: "...*desired kind **...") it seems like you're just looking to construct a value of type `Exp SrcSpanInfo` (and indeed, these types are not actually intended for kind-level usage).

To do that, just apply parameters to the constructor:

```
> span = noInfoSpan $ mkSrcSpan noLoc noLoc
> :t span
span :: SrcSpanInfo
> list = List span []
> :t list
list :: Exp SrcSpanInfo
```

---

**Original answer**

The expression `[Exp SrcSpanInfo]` does not denote "*a type-level list of types with a single element `Exp SrcSpanInfo`*", but rather denotes "*a single type that is a list of elements of type `Exp SrcSpanInfo`*", similar to `[Int]` or `[String]`.

The compiler has no way of distinguishing the former from the latter, so it defaults to the older, more standard interpretation.

In order to make it see a type-level list, it must be quoted with a single quote, just like you did with `'List`.

Further, `Exp` is a type, but when used in a kind signature, it's elevated to a kind. In order to construct a type of kind `Exp *`, you have to use [one of its constructors](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.22/haskell-src-exts-1.21.1/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t:Exp). I will use the `List` constructor, because it was the easiest to instantiate:

```
> :k 'List SrcSpanInfo '[ 'List SrcSpanInfo '[] ]
```

Comment: weird, while the list thing seems to work, the bits inside apparently are not okay yet. any insight on that?: `Expected kind ‘[Exp *]’, but ‘'[Exp SrcSpanInfo]’ has kind ‘[*]’`

Comment: Ah, right, missed that `Exp` is actually a type itself. Updated the answer.

Comment: oddly, whether I put in this, nothing, or the original from the question, in each case it's seeing kind `Exp *` instead of the desired kind `*`...

Comment: If you're using the `List` constructor, you will never get kind `*`, because its return type is `Exp l`. Regardless of what arguments you give it, the result will be `Exp l`.

Comment: It suddenly occurred to me that you may actually be confused about types vs. kinds. I have updated the answer again.

Comment: typing my function as `Exp SrcSpanInfo` was easy, yeah. I feel like this results in a loss of information though -- in this case I know more about what I have here than it just being *any* kind of expression. My impression has been `DataKinds` can help bring this additional clarity.

Comment: You misunderstand how Haskell types work. If `Exp` has been defined as a sum type including `List` and some other constructors, there is no way to specify that a particular value can be only `List`, but nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! My apologies for misunderstanding. :)

Answer (score 3):

`[a]` is the type of lists. To construct a (promoted) list, write `'[a]`:

```
:k 'List SrcSpanInfo '[ 'List Int '[] ]
```

Applying `'List` to a type, such as `SrcSpanInfo`, is probably not what you want either (hopefully my example applying it also to an `Int` tells that something is off).

Comment: Thanks! The list trick works :). I do think I intended applying the types -- eventually I wanna get out a type of kind `*`.